# Add a left "leaf" to binary tree in C

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I am learning the C language and trying to build a C binary tree library. My structure is defined as:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

typedef struct Node TNode;
typedef struct Node *binary_tree;
```

It is created like this:

```
binary_tree NewBinaryTree(int value_root) {
    binary_tree newRoot = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    if (newRoot) {
        newRoot->value = value_root;
        newRoot->left = NULL;
        newRoot->right = NULL;
    }
    return newRoot;
}
```

I add elements to it like:

```
void Insert(binary_tree *tree, int val) {
    if (*tree == NULL) {
        *tree = (binary_tree)malloc(sizeof(TNode));
        (*tree)->value = val;
        (*tree)->left = NULL;
        (*tree)->right = NULL;
    } else {
        if (val < (*tree)->value) {
            Insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
        } else {
            Insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
        }
    }
}
```

This kinda "sort" the tree by checking the value.However I would like a function that simply add the val value to the left(left) without doing any sorting. I did:

```
void InsertLeft(binary_tree *tree, int val) {
     Insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
InsertLeft(&tree, 8);
```

I have a main program that initialise the tree like this:

```
  tree = NewBinaryTree(3);
```

Also a tree display method:

```
void display_binary_tree( binary_tree tree )
{
    if( tree != NULL )
    {
        display_binary_tree( tree->left ) ;
        printf( "%d " , tree->value ) ;
        display_binary_tree( tree->right ) ;
    }
}
```

and afterwards I can add elements by calling the `Insert(binary_tree *tree, int val)` function,  however when calling this function, it just crashes the program. I dont understand why.

Comment: Try to avoid native language in code segments. It loses readability. P.S. - I like French though.

Comment: The first alternative of your `Ajouter()` function appears to do the same thing as `NouvelArbreVide()`, except `NouvelArbreVide()` does it better by accounting for memory allocation failures.  Why not just call `NouvelArbreVide()` instead of duplicating it?

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you for the advice. But in my post I am just wondering how to just add an element to the left of the tree for now

Comment: The error is probably in the code that calls these functions. Could you please provide it? As for `NouvelArbreVide`, I think it would be best to remove it and have `Ajouter` insert the root, which is possible if you initialise your empty tree to `NULL`.

Comment: @MOehm that is the problem; I did it that way because I want to initialise the tree root to a value and not NULL.Edited the post with the function call

Comment: You should not hide pointer nature behind a typedef, as you presently do with type `arbre_binaire`.  It is usually more confusing than helpful.

Comment: @ChristopherM., you seem to be missing MOehm's point about `NouvelArbreVide()`.  It is approximately the same as my earlier comment about code duplication, only he recommends de-duplicating by removing `NouvelArbreVide()` instead of by making `Ajouter()` call it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, but when I requested the calling code, I thought about having some context, too: How do you construct the tree from scractch, i.e. please show everything from `arbre_binaire arbre` up to the call of `AjouterGauche`.

Comment: ... In other words, we need a [mcve] to sort this out.

Comment: @MOehm the tree is created with arbre_binaire NouvelArbreVide(int value_root)  and I add elements to it with void Ajouter( arbre_binaire* arbre , int val ). Also edited the post with more codes I dont know what else I can add

Comment: it's called a *leaf*............

Comment: gdb or valgrind will show you why you crash

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. You should run the program in a debugger to see where the crash happens exactly and which of the dereferenced pointers is invalid.

Comment: @MOehm I just noticed something.the errors not always happen.It happen if I initialise the tree,then right after call the `void AjouterGauche(arbre_binaire *arbre, int val)`it does crash. But if I initialise the tree, then add an element with `void Ajouter(arbre_binaire *arbre, int val)` , and then call the `void AjouterGauche(arbre_binaire *arbre, int val)`, it will work

Comment: Peux-tu utiliser l'anglais pour les identificateurs dans ton programme? Ce mélange de français sans accents et de mots-clés anglais est déjà indigeste pour un adepte de la langue de Molière, il rend le code incompréhensible pour les nombreux lecteurs du monde entier sur Stack-overflow qui font l'effort d'intervenir en anglais.

Comment: Aha! By "initialise", do you mean a call to `NouvelArbreVide` or do you mean something like `arbre = NULL`? Your function `AjouterGauche` will not work for a root node that is `NULL`, but your function `Ajouter` will.

Comment: La plupart utilisent l'anglais, mais je pense que ce n'est pas la langue maternelle de la majorité d'entre eux. Cette discussion est d'ailleurs très pénible pour eux.  You seem to master English quite well, use English for the identifiers in your code too, it will make it much more readable to everyone here.

Comment: @MOehm by initialise I mean a call to  `arbre = NouvelArbreVide(3);`

Comment: Hmmm. Unless the returned value is `NULL`, which isn't very likely (but you can check), I don't see how that could happen.

Comment: @MOehm I just tried something else; I initialised the tree then added all these value: 2, 567, 34253. Then I called AjouterGauche wich worked.I then added 12 and 40, then I tried to add value 0 and it crashed.. Im lost.

Comment: @MOehm it seems that the problems is when trying to add a value afterwards calling AjouterGauche and  that is inferior to the value I added using AjouterGauche, it crash

Comment: I can't really see that happening either. The `->gauche` of all new nodes is `NULL` and `AjouterGauche` only goes left on the first node, By creating the tree with a root value, that should be safe. I think you really need to look into this in detail with a debugger.

Comment: @MOehm ok, and also I have a function the display the entire binary tree,and as soon I previously called the AjouterGauche function, the display function will not work.I will add this function to the post so you can see

Comment: @chqrlie there the post has been edited and converted to english

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130235/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-m-add-a-left-leaf-to-binary-tree-in-c).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).